# c++ going from start iterator to end iterator and performing action

Tags: c++, iterator, range, c++17, std

If I have a start iterator and an end iterator pointing to structs defined as:

```
struct point {
int x;
int y;
};
```

, and I want to go from the start iterator to the end iterator (inclusive), and one by one append the x values from the struct to a vector, how would I do this?

My issue is that with a standard for loop like:

```
for (auto it = start_iterator; it != end_iterator; ++it)
```

the end iterator will not be included, though I'm happy to use stl algorithms/libaries as well.

Comment: "*the end iterator will not be included*" - that's intented. But that doesn't mean that one of your `point`s will be excluded - iterator ranges are right-hand-side-exclusive. It means that if you have `[1, 2, 3]`, then `begin` points to `1`, but `end` points to an imaginary element **past** `3`, so `3` **will be included**. Please provide more context regarding this comment.

Comment: I want to consider the element pointed to by end_iterator though

Comment: That means your `end_iterator` is considered non-standard and you should not make design decisions that lead to this kind of problems. How do you obtain your `end_iterator`? What's its type?

Comment: @user11508332 there is no element pointed to by an end iterator.  that's the point of it pointing *past* the end...

Comment: end_iterator is a pointer to a struct point. It is obtained when I do a std::find_if with the first two parameters using rbegin() and rend() to obtain the last element (pointer to a struct point) that satisfies a ceratin criteria

Comment: After you initialized your `end_iterator` with `find_if`, simply increment it, and you'll be again within the common situation of `end_iterator`pointing one past the end.

Comment: In that case, `it.base()` already points past that found element.

Comment: @user11508332 If your iterator supports relative comparisons, you could change the condition to `it <= end_iterator` though be aware this is extremely nonstandard and anyone else reading your code is going to be very suspicious. The correct way to approach this is as everyone else has already indicated: the end iterator is exclusive. Incrementing the end iterator should handily solve the problem, assuming that your custom iterator type doesn't invoke UB in this situation.

Comment: As it is, I'm seeing guesses at what the code is actually doing. It would be far easier to reason about the question with a [mre] that shows what doesn't work so that people can adapt that to what they think is the best solution instead of working off of guesses.

Answer (score 5):

[image]Iterators in C++ is a sequence that is defined by a pair of iterators defining a half-open range [begin:end).
That is, begin points to the first element of the sequence, and end points to the one-beyond-the-last element of the sequence.

Reference : The C++ Programming Language : Stroustrup.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `end_iterator` **actually points to an element** (meaning it's safe to get an iterator that's one past it), you can use `std::next` from `<iterator>`:

```
for (auto it = start_iterator; it != std::next(end_iterator); ++it) { ... }
```